# Reasonable and Logical Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions, leibniz-integral-rule

$\lim _{k\to +\infty}$ $\int_{0}^{k[x]} (kt-[kt])^k dt$ $;$ $k\in N$ is $[\frac{\lambda x} 2]$

Where $[.]$ denotes greatest Integer function then the value of $\lambda$ would be?

My approach to this question was using [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) which didn't  work out instead of making it lengthy , even used every single property of greatest Integer function but still I'm missing something. What would be a better approach instead of Leibniz integral rule? Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the substitution $u = kt$, we have,
\begin{align*}
I & = \int_{0}^{k[x]} (kt - [kt])^k \ \mathrm{d}t \\
& = \frac{1}{k} \int_{0}^{k^2[x]} (u - [u])^k \ \mathrm{d}u \\
& = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{r = 0}^{k^2[x]-1}\int_{r}^{r+1} (u - [u])^k \ \mathrm{d}u \\
& = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{r = 0}^{k^2[x]-1}\int_{0}^{1} ((u-r) - [u-r])^k \ \mathrm{d}u \\
& = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{r = 0}^{k^2[x]-1}\int_{0}^{1} ((u-r) - ([u]-r))^k \ \mathrm{d}u \\
& = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{r = 0}^{k^2[x]-1}\int_{0}^{1} (u - [u])^k \ \mathrm{d}u \\
& = \frac{k^2[x]}{k} \int_{0}^{1} (u - [u])^k \ \mathrm{d}u \\
& = {k[x]} \int_{0}^{1} u^k \ \mathrm{d}u \\
& = \frac{k[x]}{k+1}.
\end{align*}

Consequently, $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} I = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k[x]}{k+1} = [x]$. Hence, $\lambda = 2$.

Comment: Is it like you have to keep the upper limit in form of a constant only? why can't we evaluate keeping the limits same

Comment: And Have you seen these type of question before because I found it randomly and which source can I refer for these type of questions?

Comment: And please can you mention what all properties you are using

Comment: I have expanded the solution for better understandability. In fifth step is use the fact that for any $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $[x + r] = [x] + r$. Sixth step uses $[x] = 0$ for $x \in (0,1)$.

Comment: Did you use the summation concept when k tends to infinity(Limit as a sum)?In 3rd step

Comment: No I have not. Note that I have evaluated $I$ for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and taken the limit later on. In the third step, I split the integral across different intervals. It is equivalent to writing $\int_0^2 f(x) \ \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1 f(x) \ \mathrm{d}x + \int_1^2 f(x) \ \mathrm{d}x$. Just instead of 2 integrals I split it over $k^2[x]$ of them.

Comment: Can you please explain how did you break sigma function and Integration in 3rd step